# Not able to set credentails at ansible tower

Tags: ansible, devops, ansible-tower

I'm trying to create credentials at ansible tower but getting error
should not be set when SSH key is not encrypted.
Authentication method is via private key and passphrase . [image]

Comment: Drag and drop your ssh private key file into `SSH Private Key` section in the Credentials.

Comment: The error message implies that the private key is not encrypted, so perhaps you are trying to use user's password in addition to the key? In this case you should use `PASSWORD` field.

Comment: On SO, the playbook tag is used for question related to Blackberry Playbook, not Ansible playbook.